# Displaying edge labels in prefuse (java) graphs

Tags: java, graph, label, edges, prefuse

I'm new to prefuse (Java) and would like to display edge labels in a graph.
I've been searching for this but could not find the solution.

Any idea about this?

Comment: You need to use decorators, see example below

Answer (score 1):

I came here with the same question. But it seems the previous link is **broken**.

I found this version and it runs ok.

http://netgrok.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/src/test/AggregateDecoratorDemo.java